# Could there be an "$n$-th root" of the category $\mathsf{Set}$?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, topos-theory

Here is a thought experiment: Suppose we did not know what sets and functions are. The general idea of a topos is, that it somehow serves as a foundation for mathematics. So let there be an alternate world and a well known topos $\mathcal{A}$, "in which everyone does mathematics", in this world. Eventually, some category theorist claims: "Oh, our mathematical universe is not as 'fundamental' as we think. I found a topos that I henceforth shall call $\mathsf{Set}$ and an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (not $1$) such that $\mathcal{A}$ is equivalent to $\mathsf{Set}^n$" (because $\mathcal{A}$ was $\mathsf{Set}^{45634}$ all along, for example).

Let us come back to this world with the obvious question:

> Could there be a category $\sqrt[n]{\mathcal{\mathsf{Set}}}$ and an $n\in \mathbb{N}, n>1$ with $\sqrt[n]{\mathcal{\mathsf{Set}}}^n $ equivalent to $\mathsf{Set}$?

What if instead the $n$ is any small category besides $1$?

There might be an issue with this question: I am not sure, what "category" really should mean in this context. Possibly, the "right" answer assumes, that category theory deals with categories internal to $\sqrt[n]{\mathcal{\mathsf{Set}}}$. I do not know that, since I am no expert by any means.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. First things first: by a symmetry argument, we see that the diagonal of $\mathcal{C}^n$ is closed under whatever limits or colimits exist in $\mathcal{C}$; in particular, if $\mathcal{C}^n$ has finite limits and colimits, then so does $\mathcal{C}$. Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ has a terminal object $1$ and the binary coproduct $1 + 1$. Then,
$$\mathcal{C}^n ((1, \ldots, 1), (1 + 1, \ldots, 1 + 1)) \cong \mathcal{C} (1, 1 + 1)^n$$
and in particular, if this set is finite, then the number of elements is an $n$-th power. But if $\mathcal{C}^n$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}$, this forces $n = 1$.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, we are actually using the fact, that $\sqrt[n]{2}$ is only an integer, if $n=1$. Interesting.

Comment: Zhen, what can you say about the more general question of whether $\text{Set} \cong C \times D$ for two non-terminal categories $C, D$? Intuitively this is impossible at least in the case that $C, D$ are themselves categories of sheaves on spaces, since the one-point space is connected.

Comment: That's a more interesting question. It would be enough to show that the maximal subgroupoid has no interesting product decompositions – then it becomes a question of homotopy theory.

Comment: Asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617592/is-set-prime-with-respect-to-the-cartesian-product