# Is Set "prime" with respect to the cartesian product?

Tags: category-theory

(Motivated by Stefan Perko's question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617053/could-there-be-an-n-th-root-of-the-category-mathsfset))

> Suppose $C, D$ are two categories such that $\text{Set} \cong C \times D$. Is either $C$ or $D$ necessarily equivalent to the terminal category $1$?

I haven't thought about it much, but my guess is that the answer is yes. Consider, for example, the special case that $C$ and $D$ are categories of sheaves on spaces. We have $\text{Sh}(X) \times \text{Sh}(Y) \cong \text{Sh}(X + Y)$ (where $+$ denotes coproduct), and $\text{Sh}(1) \cong \text{Set}$, so (after restricting to sober spaces) being able to write $\text{Set}$ as a product of sheaf topoi corresponds to decomposing the one-point space $1$ as a disjoint union, but of course no nontrivial such decomposition is possible.

I can show that either $C$ or $D$ must have a zero object, which settles the question if $C$ and $D$ are required to be topoi.

Comment: The functor sending a category to its maximal subgroupoid is a right adjoint, so it preserves products in particular. It therefore suffices to show that the maximal subgroupoid of $\mathbf{Set}$ is "prime". If we assume GCH, there is an easy argument: supposing both factors are non-trivial, one has a connected component with non-trivial finite $\pi_1$ and the other has a connected component with $\pi_1$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$, so the product will have at least  _two_ connected components with $\pi_1$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$, but this is impossible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Suppose you have an equivalence $Set\cong C\times D$ where $C$ and $D$ are both nontrivial.  Let $(0_C,0_D)$ be a pair of objects corresponding to the empty set.  Then $0_C$ and $0_D$ must be initial and we must have that if there exist maps $c\to 0_C$ and $d\to 0_D$, then $c\cong 0_C$ and $d\cong 0_D$ (since no nonempty set can map to the empty set).  In particular, taking $d=0_D$, we find that every object of $C$ that maps to $0_C$ is initial, and similarly for $0_D$.  Since $C$ and $D$ are both nontrivial, we can choose objects $c\in C$ and $d\in D$ which are not initial.  Note that there are then no maps $(c,0_D)\to(0_C,d)$, since there are no maps $c\to 0_C$.  But this is impossible, because $(0_C,d)\not\cong (0_C,0_D)$ so $(0_C,d)$ must correspond to a nonempty set, and every set can map to every nonempty set.

---

Here's another argument, which is more similar in spirit to the arguments for other categories I sketched in comments below.  Let $(0_C,0_D)$ be as above and let $(1_C,1_D)$ be the terminal object.  Note that $(1_C,1_D)$ is the coproduct of $(1_C,0_D)$ and $(0_C,1_D)$.  Since the terminal object of $Set$ cannot be written as a coproduct unless one of the summands is initial, this implies either $1_C\cong 0_C$ or $1_D\cong 0_D$; suppose $1_C\cong 0_C$.  Then for any $c\in C$, note that there is exactly one map from $(0_C,1_D)\cong (1_C,1_D)$ to $(c,1_D)$.  But this means that as a set, $(c,1_D)$ has one point, so it is terminal, so $c\cong 1_C$.  Thus every object in $C$ is terminal and $C$ is trivial.

Comment: Oh, this is very nice; thanks! It's unfortunate that your argument doesn't generalize with $\text{Set}$ replaced by, say, $\text{Ab}$. But I suppose that's a question for another day. I'll refrain from accepting for now because I'm sure there are many other possible approaches (I have one in mind myself) and it'd be nice to collect them.

Comment: In a category with biproducts, a product decomposition of the category is equivalent to a pair of full subcategories $C$ and $D$ that have no nonzero maps between them such that every object is a biproduct of an object of $C$ and an object of $D$.  From this criterion it is easy to get that $R$-Mod is "prime" whenever $R$ is a ring with no nontrivial idempotents (since $R$ is indecomposable as a module, so it must be in either $C$ or $D$, but it can map to every nonzero module).

Comment: Oh I see, because $c \times d$ is the biproduct of $c$ and $d$. That's also very nice!

Comment: Oh, actually what I said above works in any category with a zero object; the existence of biproducts of objects of $C$ with objects of $D$ then follows automatically from the product decomposition.  In particular, this  tells you that a category with a zero object and no nontrivial biproducts (such as Grp, or pointed sets) is prime.

Comment: I like your second argument a lot; it validates my intuition that this is a "connectedness" issue (you use crucially the fact that the terminal object in $\text{Set}$ is indecomposable wrt coproduct).

Comment: Right, that's the idea.  To refine the idea a bit, I think that the examples of categories with zero object show that the key point is that a generator is indecomposable, rather than that the terminal object is indecomposable; it's kind of a coincidence that the indecomposable generator happens to be terminal for $Set$.