# How to show that the category of finite vector spaces is indecomposable?

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories

In [1] it is said that the category $\mathbf{FinVect}$ of finite vector spaces is a tensor category. I am trying to convince myself that this is indeed the case.

One of the properties that $\mathbf{FinVect}$ must satisfy for this to hold is that it is indecomposable. I cannot think of a way to show that. Here are the definitions which are relevant for this problem:

**Def:** Let $\mathbb C$ be a locally finite $\mathbb{K}$-linear abelian rigid monoidal category.
$\mathbb{C}$ is a *multitensor category* over $\mathbb{K}$ if $\otimes:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is bilinear on morphisms.
A multitensor category $\mathbb{C}$ is *decomposable* if it is equivalent to a direct sum of nonzero multitensor categories.
If $\mathbb{C}$ is an indecomposable multitensor category and $\text{End}(1)\cong \mathbb{K}$ (as vector spaces), then $\mathbb{C}$ is a *tensor category*.

[1] Pavel Etingof et al. Tensor Categories. American Mathematical Society,
2015.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from $\mathbb K$ being indecomposable ? Indeed take if $\mathbf{FinVect} \simeq C_1\times C_2$ then with $\mathbb K$ corresponding to, say $(a,b)$ we would have $\hom(\mathbb{K,K}) \cong \hom(a,a)\times \hom(b,b)$. So one of $a$ or $b$ is $0$ and then it should follow from there (and the generating character of $\mathbb K$) that $C_1$ or $C_2$ is $0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mathbf{FinVect}\simeq C\times D$ where $C$ and $D$ are both nonzero, let $c$ and $d$ be nonzero objects of $C$ and $D$, respectively.  Then $(c,0)$ and $(0,d)$ are both nonzero objects of $C\times D$ (because their identity map is not equal to their zero map), but $\operatorname{Hom}((c,0),(0,d))\cong \operatorname{Hom}(c,0)\times\operatorname{Hom}(0,d)\cong 0$.  This is a contradiction, since any two nonzero vector spaces have a nonzero linear map between them.

For some similar arguments for other categories, see my answer at [Is Set "prime" with respect to the cartesian product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617592/is-set-prime-with-respect-to-the-cartesian-product) and its comments.